# MEF - is it possible to list all imports required by an assembly (without reflection)?

Tags: c#, mef

Is there any elegant MEF way to list all (property and constructor) imports of a given interface for a given assembly?

I realize I can scan all the exported types with reflection, checking for `[Import]` or `[ImportingConstructor]` attributes (and so on), but I think that MEF already knows that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elegant** is just too subjective, so I hope my solution fits your concept of elegance =)

You can use [ReflectionModelServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.reflectionmodel.reflectionmodelservices?view=netframework-4.7.1) class, which is at **System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel**. As its name implies it uses Reflection internally, but well, is part of MEF and MEF uses reflection.

When you said **without reflection** I assume you refer to using reflection directly on the type. So, lets go on...

Let say we have the following:

```
internal interface IFoo { }

internal class Boo : IFoo
{
    [Import] public string SomeString;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Boo(int someInt) { }
}

internal class Moo : IFoo
{
    [Import] public float SomeFloat;
}
```

Then wherever you are creating your catalogs (for me it happened to be in Main of a Console application) you iterate over your catalog's parts and inspect each part's import definitions:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var regBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();
    regBuilder.ForTypesMatching(t => typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .Export<IFoo>();
    var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), regBuilder);

    foreach (var composablePartDefinition in catalog.Parts)
        if (typeof(IFoo).IsAssignableFrom(ReflectionModelServices.GetPartType(composablePartDefinition).Value))
            foreach (var importDefinition in composablePartDefinition.ImportDefinitions)
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Contract name: {importDefinition.ContractName}. Is parameter (for ImportingConstructor stuff): {ReflectionModelServices.IsImportingParameter(importDefinition)}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output for this is:

[image]

You can try to explore other properties that define ImportDefinition, for example you may want to know the cardinality or the share policy, both of them are there... =)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's what I needed, it's short, it's fast (no need to run Reflection twice, as MEF already did it), it's informative -  it's elegant! :)